# Kafka with docker

Tags: apache-kafka, dockerfile, docker-compose

I want to install a kafka image in my docker, I have tried with https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/wurstmeister/kafka/, but when I write in command line docker pull wurstmeister/kafka, I got this error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: /tmp/download-kafka.sh: Permission denied
Service 'kafka' failed to build: The command [/bin/sh -c /tmp/download-kafka.sh] returned a non-zero code: 126
```

Anybody knows the problem?

Comment: are you sure, you just wrote `docker pull wurstmeister/kafka` in command line? docker pull just pulls the image and the error you are getting seems something else.

Comment: yes I'm sure and I don't know the problem. I know that docker just pulls the image..... Maybe something of my OS.

Comment: I had problems with that docker image, and  now I use kafka ches image  https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/ches/kafka/

Answer (score 0):

You should add to Dockerfile line:

```
RUN chmod +x /tmp/download-kafka.sh && sleep 1
```

Your issue looks the same with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33957312/permission-issues-with-own-built-docker-container-with-elasticsearch-2-1)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it turned out to be caused by download-kafka.sh having Windows style EOL (CRLF instead of LF) when cloned. If you are running on a Windows machine, make sure that you configure git with core.autocrlf false.

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add `RUN chmod 777 /tmp/download-kafka.sh`
to kafka.Dockerfile just before executing `RUN /tmp/download-kafka.sh`

Comment: `chmod 777` -> nononoNONO**NONONO**! Please never do this. This will have it readable **and** writable for **everyone** on the system. You almost never need to do this. Set the correct user and/or group.