# Permission issues with own built Docker container with Elasticsearch 2.1

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, containers

When I pull an image from public elasticsearch repo, spawning container with that pulled image is working fine for me with no permission issues.

```
docker pull elasticsearch

docker run -d elasticsearch
```

But when I spawn a container with the Dockerfile which is available there with the public repo gives me permission issues. I do have a same directory structure as public repo.

```
myfolder/Dockerfile

myfolder/docker-entrypoint.sh

myfolder/config/elasticsearch.yml

myfolder/config/logging.yml


https://github.com/docker-library/elasticsearch/tree/0d393d9a0a2e24fca022a89ad10c7050b2925292/2.1
```

Commands:-
1) To build an image with the Dockerfile

```
sudo docker build -t testuser/testelastic:v1 .
```

2) Spawn container out of the built image

```
sudo docker run -d --name elastic -v ./config:/config testuser/testelastic:v1
```

But it gives me following error everytime when I tried to spawn any container out of the above custom build image.

```
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 8e72f3c33d054f5883b2de9e7673bc032333e633e3f43905d7d22a12ea76ad04: [8] System error: exec: "/docker-entrypoint.sh": permission denied
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
chmod +x docker-entrypoint.sh
```

You need the script to be executable. Then build and run.